# Can npx (or npm exec) use a lockfile directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npx

I know I can use `npx` in a local directory and it will pick up the `node_modules` folder and run executables from there, but is there any way to pass a `package-lock.json` to `npx` when installing into the global cache (`~/.npm/_npx`)?

For example, does something like this exist?:

```bash
# From a directory, with no node_modules

npx --from-lockfile=package-lock.json cowsay "Is this possible?"
# or
npm exec --from-lockfile=package-lock.json cowsay "Is this possible?"
```

I know that the workaround is something like:

```bash
npm ci
npx cowsay "Running from local node_modules based on package-lock.json"
```